# Displaying Percentages Sorted DESC Correctly

Tags: mysql

I have some data that I would like to display as a percentage instead of decimal. I've handled this with:

```
 concat((left(percentcompleted, 4)*100), '%') as Percent
```

I'm using the LEFT because the column I'm pulling from is a DECIMAL(35,15) and cannot be changed currently.

I'm taking this data and using Microsoft PowerBI to display it and would like to be able to sort DESC and have 100% be at the top. Unfortunately this, because it becomes a VARCHAR puts 100% near the bottom, below even 2%.

How could I have this sort DESC correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging into this more it seems that it cannot work in the way I want. I'd need to use:

```
 order by cast(column as unsigned) asc
```

This helps inside MySQL but not with the PowerBI front-end.